# Why Julia works much slower than MATLAB when taking inverse of a matrix?

Tags: julia

Same code piece in MATLAB works 5-8 times faster than Julia ? How can I speed up Julia?

I just simply write

```
  inv(rand(5000,5000))
  inv(rand(10000,10000))
```

both are muuch much slower than MATLAB

Comment: Might be that multithreading isn't activated for the blas version Julia is using, but is activated in Matlab.

Comment: On my pc the difference is <25%. Try to change the number of threads used by BLAS in Julia: `BLAS.set_num_threads(4)` or some other number depending on the number of cores. Also Matlab uses MKL while Julia uses OpenBLAS, and MKL is probably a bit faster.

Comment: If you have a license for MKL you can use it to build Julia: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#intel-mkl.

Comment: Or you can check out MKL.jl.

Comment: As it's been said Julia does not ship with Intel MKL unlike MATLAB. You can compile [Julia with MKL from source](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia#intel-mkl), or rebuild Julia system image using [MKL.jl](https://github.com/JuliaComputing/MKL.jl). Intel MKL is distributed *free of charge*.

Even with OpenBLAS, as @DNF pointed out, setting number of BLAS threads to the number of physical (not logical) cores should help. The difference on my computer with OpenBLAS and MKL is also  <25% but yours might be a little bit more if you have a CPU with AVX-512 instructions but not 5-8 times.

Comment: @DNF  i think the problem is not about BLAS threads 

          ccall((:openblas_get_num_threads64_, Base.libblas_name), Cint, ()) 

gives me o result of 8 

I will look for MKL

Comment: initially BLAS threads were setted to 8 I set them to 4. Now time consumption down from 90 seconds to 35 seconds. Thank you.